# You must pass a valid ReactElement | Sweetalert-react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sweetalert

I am trying to use the `sweetalert-react` package (https://github.com/chentsulin/sweetalert-react) as a modal for my app.
Right now I got it to work, but I want to be able to display a const that has my component:

```
const clusterDoors = lock.doors.map(clusterDoor => {
  return (
    <div key={clusterDoor.port_id}>
      <ClusterListItem
        clusterDoor={clusterDoor}
        customer={
          clusterDoor.allocation.customer ? (
            keyedCustomers[clusterDoor.allocation.customer]
          ) : (
            false
          )
        }
        .....
```

So I read their docs and found out that I can achieve that with `ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup`. So I simple need to:

```
text={renderToStaticMarkup(<MyComponent />)}
```

But the problem is that my component is inside of a constant, so if I try to do:

```
text={renderToStaticMarkup({clusterDoors})}
```

I will get the error:

> You must pass a valid ReactElement.

I wonder if there's some workaround to this?

I did some research and tried also tried to do:

```
const clusterDoors = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    lock.doors.map(clusterDoor => {
      return (
        <div key={clusterDoor.port_id}>
          <ClusterListItem
            clusterDoor={clusterDoor}
            customer={
              clusterDoor.allocation.customer ? (
                keyedCustomers[clusterDoor.allocation.customer]
              ) : (
                false
              )
            }
            delivery={
              clusterDoor.allocation.delivery ? (
                keyedDeliveries[clusterDoor.allocation.delivery]
              ) : (
                false
              )
            }
          />
        </div>
      )
    })
  }
})
```

But that didn't do the trick.

If I pass it a valid react component (`ClusterListItem`) my app won't break, but nothing will show because of the `array clusterDoor` wont exist.

I hope I explained my situation well. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Try `text={renderToStaticMarkup(<div>{clusterDoors}</div>)}`

Comment: What is `keyedCustomers[clusterDoor.allocation.customer]`? Why is the false condition set as `false` in your ternary? does `keyedCustomers[clusterDoor.allocation.customer]` actually return `true`?

Comment: @Prakashsharma You were correct. If you make an answer I will accept it. Thanks.

Comment: @Andrew No it doesnt return anything right now actually. Which is weird because `keyedDeliveries[clusterDoor.allocation.delivery]` does return objects. And `keyedDeliveries` and `keyedCustomers` have the same data structure.

Comment: @MartinNordström That sounds like a different question to ask, but I'm very surprised you're not getting an error when that tries to render, unless `keyedCustomers` always exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are passing an array of elements because `clusterDoors` is an array and `renderToStaticMarkup` is expecting a single element. Therefore you are getting this error.

**Solution**: Just wrap your array in a `div` tag so it becomes a single node element like this

```
text={renderToStaticMarkup(<div>{clusterDoors}</div>)}
```